# How to download media files in WhatsApp API which send users?

Tags: json, whatsapp

I am currently writing a chatbot for WhatsApp.
I use the [360dialog](https://www.360dialog.com/) platform, which makes it possible to work with the *WhatsApp Business API*.

When the client sends a message, I see the following JSON object in the logs of my application:

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "from": "77773336633",
            "id": "ABGGd3c1cGY_Ago61ytHsZknvtLv",
            "image": {
                "id": "ffd23134-2dae-4fed-b5f8-0ce7867b6ddd",
                "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
                "sha256": "bd02100d961b5a1dbaae1dd645485ebbfeda77b44e82c015f1cf29b05654ccb9"
            },
            "timestamp": "1605703542",
            "type": "image"
        }
    ],
    "contacts": [
        {
            "profile": {
                "name": "Nurzhan Nogerbek"
            },
            "wa_id": "77773336633"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't find any information in the documentation about how to download this file.
In my case, I want to upload this image file that the client sends to my file storage.
Please tell me which URL method from the WhatsApp API is responsible for this mechanism?

**P.S.** At the same time, I can send files to clients. This information is available on the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages).

Answer (score 3):

It was very tricky because postman worked, but c# didn't work for me, and I spent two days trying to find the solution and finally did the following code, which works in C#:

```
using HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
Uri uri = new Uri(mediaUrl);
var fileName = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")}.jpeg";
string filePath = $"Files\\{fileName}";

// NOTE: to save bandwidth, request compressed content
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Clear();
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("br"));

// NOTE: accept all languages
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Clear();
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("*"));

// NOTE: accept all media types
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));

_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("image/jpeg"));

var productValue = new ProductInfoHeaderValue("ScraperBot", "1.0");
var commentValue = new ProductInfoHeaderValue("(+http://www.API.com/ScraperBot.html)");
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(productValue);
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(commentValue);

_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", {WhatsApp_Access_Token});
    
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var mediaType = response?.Content?.Headers?.ContentType?.MediaType ?? string.Empty;

var imageBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fs.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
}
```

Here, {WhatsApp_Access_Token} is your Whatsapp API permanent token.

Ping me in a comment, please, if you have any issues or questions.

Comment: This is the best solution, but I have been purposely avoiding it due to the web scraping. I found the proper user agent needs to be: _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("WhatsApp/2.19.81 A");

Answer (score 2):

May be it will help, just try, take a look:-

```
const URL = `https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/?mid=1104480873777230&ext=1662705250&hash=ATuMx352sLrhKUegbQZSC8oLl3J5Vy3Z49lO4HwTUKWRYQ`;
const FROM = `video`;

const config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: URL, //PASS THE URL HERE, WHICH YOU RECEIVED WITH THE HELP OF MEDIA ID
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  },
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
};
axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    const ext = response.headers['content-type'].split("/")[1];
    fs.writeFileSync(`${FROM}.${ext}`, response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: I am getting json in console.log(ext), can you help me with this

Answer (score 1):

I saw this thread and it finally helped me getting the solution. Here is the entire C# code from retrieving a media id inside the whatsapp message. The problem without the agent is that facebook responds with a message that the browser is not supported without it.

```
string whatsappBaseUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/";
string mediaId = "id you received in message";
string accesstoken =  "Your Whatsapp Access Token";
string agentHeader =  "WhatsApp/2.19.81 A";

_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accesstoken);
string url = $"{whatsappBaseUrl}{mediaId}";

var getMediaUrl = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);

if (getMediaUrl.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(agentHeader);
   
    var response = await _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(mediaUrl);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(response);
}
```

Comment: this line of code was the key for me: string agentHeader =  "WhatsApp/2.19.81 A";

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation has a session for this in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/media.

Basically you must make a GET request to download the media.

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://waba.360dialog.io/v1/media/{media id} \
  --header 'D360-API-KEY: {your api token}'
```

Comment: With this were you able to solve? A very long string returns to me how can I save the image on the server?

Comment: this solution does not work.

Comment: The documentation has been modified and the new url is this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/media/media-id

Comment: When you make the request, the server will return a blob to you.
You need to read that blob and assign it to a Buffer. (Buffer.from(response.data).toString('base64'))
After that you can do whatever you want with the media content.

Comment: @AlanFacchini using Axios I get a blank file, please help

`const fileContents = Buffer.from(
       mediaDownloadResults.data
              ).toString("base64");

              fs.writeFile(document.id + ".pdf", fileContents, (err) => {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                console.log("file saved to ");
              });`

Answer (score 0):

For the entire message cycle (receiving the request, downloading the audio file, and transcribing it with OpenAI's Whisper), in Python:

Define the function for retrieving the file, saving and transcribing:

```
def retrieve_text(media_id, audio_name = 'received_audio'):
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{media_id}/" # the media id obtained in the webhook
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}' } # enter your access token here

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers) # get the message
    file_url = response.json()['url'] # get the file url
    response = requests.get(file_url, headers=headers) # get the file binary

    open(audio_name+'.ogg', 'wb').write(response.content) # save the received file
    audio_file = open(audio_name+'.ogg', "rb") # open the file
    transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audio_file) # transcribe with OpenAI API
    return transcript.text # return the transcription
```

Then, upon receiving the request in your Webhook:

```
incoming_msg = request.json
#messages = incoming_msg['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]
media_id = message[0]['audio']['id']
retrieve_text(media_id)
```